# How to publish webjobs targeting netcoreapp2.1 with WebJobs SDK 3.0 to Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, publish, azure-webjobs

Just migrated my webjobs to `netcoreapp2.1` now that WebJobs SDK `v3.0.0` is officially out. Migration went smoothly but I can no longer figure out the proper way to publish those from Visual Studio to Azure.

Here are few attempts which all failed:

1. With SDK `v2.x.x`, I used the `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` NuGet package in order to get the additional right-click context entry `Publish as WebJobs...`.
   Now adding this package no longer adds the context entry.
2. I tried the classic `Publish...` option. This one seems to have been updated in some way to support webjobs as I can select some options in the dialog like the webjobs name or type (`Continuous` or `Triggered`). Problem is publish does nothing in that case (files are not pushed to my webapp at all).
3. I tried to mix both options by creating a new profile with this new flow while still adding the NuGet `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` with `webjob-publish-settings.json` file in `Properties` folder of my project. In that case contextual menu is still not displayed but classic `Publish...` at least now pushes some files to my webapp. Problem in that case is Kudo does not seem to detect it as a webjob and does not run it.
4. I tried to update the publish profile to force the publish process to generate an `EXE` file (console netcoreapp.2.1 are `DLL` files by default). This was still not working. Publish process creates a new sub folder for the targeted platform in the publish dir and creates the `EXE` in it but I think Kudu is not scanning sub folders for webjobs executable.

Finally I found [that article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/08/22/webjobs-in-azure-with-net-core-2-1/) which is full of hacks and I personally want to avoid for maintenance purpose...

Did anyone figure out a proper way to publish from Visual Studio in that case?

Comment: Back link to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/745) that prompted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what happened but when creating yet another publish profile this time my `.csproj` got updated to add `;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish` in `Project` tag. With that additional SDK reference, publish is working fine.

`.csproj` prior update (not working)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

`.csproj` after update (working)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
```